# Is it possible to run a Rails 4.2 app on Ruby 2.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.4

I want to try out a Rails 4.2 app on Ruby 2.4.

However, when I try doing it, I get errors about the json gem version 1.8.3 failing to install.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
/Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0-rc1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161223-91367-cql0ne.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
generator.c:861:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cFixnum'
    } else if (klass == rb_cFixnum) {
                        ^
generator.c:863:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cBignum'
    } else if (klass == rb_cBignum) {
                        ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.4.0-static/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

which I assume is due to the unification of Fixnum and Bignum into Integer.

If I add to the Gemfile a constraint that json has to be version 2.0.0, then it complains that Rails 4.2 requires json ~> 1.7, which forbids 2.0.0.

Am I out of luck unless the maintainers of Rails decide to make a change to a non-5.x version of Rails, or the maintainers of the json gem decide to make a new non-2.x version of their gem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is now possible with rails [4.2.8.rc1](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2017/2/11/this-week-in-rails-ruby-2-4-on-rails-4-2/) (February 11th 2017)

Answer (score 16):

The `json` gem has a fix on the `1.8` branch. Hopefully it'll be released as a gem soon, but in the meantime you can use it directly in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'json', github: 'flori/json', branch: 'v1.8'
```

Rails has also [merged a fix](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/25161) to the `4-2-stable` branch about a week after the latest official `4.2.x` gem release. Hopefully they'll release a new gem soon too, but this might help in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: '4-2-stable'
```

Finally, you may need to load `arel` from a git source as well:

```
gem 'arel', github: 'rails/arel', branch: '6-0-stable'
```

With those three changes I was able to boot our app and query the database, but then ran into other Integer unification related issues. Seems like this change to going to cause some waves.

Comment: Since posting this answer, ruby 2.4 compatible versions of json (`1.8.5`) and arel (`6.0.4`) have been released. The main thing we're waiting on now is a new rails `4.2.x` release.

Comment: .. and now rails 4.2.8 has been released, which should be enough to get apps booting on ruby 2.4. It's likely a few second and third level dependencies will print deprecations, but hopefully they're not fatal

Answer (score 7):

Upgrade rails to rails-4.2.8 .This is the first 4.2.x version that officially supports ruby-2.4

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it won't be possible at the moment (Although it sounds odd).

See the [Changelog for the JSON gem](https://github.com/flori/json/blob/master/CHANGES.md#2015-09-11-200). Json 2.0.0 adds compatibility for ruby 2.4, but rails 4.2 restricts json to 1.x